# jqGrid. Error to make the sum of a column "Cannot use object of type stdClass"

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I'm trying the following example of [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start):

http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx
   Functionality Misc
   Footer Customization

and get the error detailed below:

**Fatal error**:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
**C:\htdocs\proyect\js\jquery\jqGrid\php\jqGrid.php(1) :
eval()'d code** on line **1**

The error occurs when you want to sum the column "Freight.":

PHP:

```
$summaryrows = array("Freight"=>array("Freight"=>"SUM"));
```

The jqGrid version we are using is "3.8.2.1" and PHP "5.3.1".

What is the problem?

Comment: I don't receive the described error on the page which you described. Which web browser you use? Do you use the page or try to implement yourself the same behavior in your code?

Comment: I replicate the example that I detail in my PC, can not be error to the browser because the error is in PHP. The problem is I have to want to total the column.

Comment: Probably the best would be to post the question to the forum http://www.trirand.net/forum/

Comment: Yes, we're going to send the query to jqGrid forum, just put the version 3.8.1.1 and works perfectly. We are sure that is a problem with version 3.8.2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you can see the bug and the solution:
http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=4070&#post4070